# Temporarily disable certain bound actions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a field is focused or blurred, a jQuery Ajax request fires. I don't want the Ajax request to fire if there's already a request being called. Here's what I have:

```
$('#domain').bind('change focus blur', function() {
    // Disable the "bind" here
    $.getJSON(theURL, '', function(data) {
      ...
    });
    // Re-enable the "bind" here
});
```

Comment: I created a function queue for another question that you could modify and re-use.  It's at http://jsfiddle.net/6tvTD/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [`unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)?

```
function handler() {
    $('#domain').unbind('change focus blur', handler);

    $.getJSON(theURL, '', function(data) {
        // ...

        $('#domain').bind('change focus blur', handler);
    });
}

$('#domain').bind('change focus blur', handler);
```

Comment: So you'd have to wrap handler() in another bind() call?

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable outside the scope of the bind function and use it to track whether a request is in progress. Make sure to re-enable only after the json returned. If you re-enable where you have your comment the request could still be in progress, but the execution would have continued beyond the getJson call.

```
var blocking = false;
    $('#domain').bind('change focus blur',function(){
        if(!blocking)
        {
             blocking = true;
             $.getJSON(theURL,'',function(data){
                blocking = false;
            });

            // Re-enable the "bind" here - no, not here. you should re-enable on the callback from the ajax call. 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#domain').bind('change focus blur',function(){

    //check if blocked        
    if ($(this).data("blocked")) return;

    // Disable the "bind" here
    $(this).data("blocked", 1);

    $.getJSON(theURL,'',function(data){

    });
    // Re-enable the "bind" here
    $(this).data("blocked", 0);
});
```